# open debugger window - Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, adb

I want to debug my app. 
That was all the time no problem:

click on debug icon -> app starts -> stop at breakpoint -> debug window open

Now the debugger still stops at the breakpoint but the debugging window with the variables inside does not open and I am not able to find a way how to open it...

As you can see Android Studio is in the debug mode but the debugging window does not open:

[image]

So how can I open the debugger window in Android Studio where all the variables are shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window is already in open state. Mouse over on top of the Debug tab in bottom bar and drag to top inorder to open up the window. There you can see Variables|Console tab.

Comment: when I drag the debug tab in bottom bar to top border of the windows the tab just pops back and nothing happens... can you explain it please more detailed?

Comment: Upon mouse over, you could see a drag icon on top of the Debug tab. From your screenshot attached, Debug tab is in selected mode and so i guessed.