# Does Android Studio have the equivalent of view debug like xcode?

Tags: android-studio, debugging, view-debugging

I am trying to quickly learn a new code-base (android-based) and a great way of doing that in iOS is using xcode's view debugger.

I do not know where to place break-points right now as there are way too many classes.  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588471/open-debugger-window-android-studio

Comment: That's not what I'm referring to.  I'm referring to being able to see what fragments/activities are currently open.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% identical but you can use Layout inspector
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector